# Query Does not incluse expression as a part of aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

below table is a shorter version of my table. I want to aggregate two columns which have common Id. The role of security does not matter, but cannot remove it from my select statement.

```
INPUT

Security           MValue        BValue          ID 
 ABH23              50             55             1  
 ABH52              20             20             2
 ABH96              30             35             3
 LOH27              80             70             3
 LOH52              10             15             2
 KLO12              70             60             1

OUTPUT

 Security             MValue        BValue          ID 
 Doesn't Matter       120             115            1  
 Doesn't Matter       30              35             2
 Doesn't Matter       110             105            3

SELECT Security,sum(MValue),sum(Bvalue),ID Group BY ID
```

Now I understand that after aggregating there will be multiple security value for one record but I don't care as which one gets selected in my final output, but I am sure there is a way to solve this.

Comment: You should tag the question with "mysql" or "oracle" but not both (unless you have a question that relates to both databases).  Based on the error, I am guessing that you are using Oracle.

Comment: Sorry for that but I was prompted that I use oracle tag as I will get better answers. I am using this query in VBA.

Comment: If you're working in MySQL, why on earth would you think that answers given assuming you're on an Oracle database would be better? They are completely separate databases, and whilst some queries may well run on both databases, there's no guarantee. You should use the correct tag for your database platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select one use `min()` or `max()`:

```
SELECT MIN(Security), sum(MValue), sum(Bvalue), ID
FROM ???
Group BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have many columns like this, so will this work if the column is a string?

Comment: @user3504466 . . . `MIN()` and `MAX()` work on almost all data types, including strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select Security, MValue, BValue, ID  from 
(
SELECT Row_number()over(partition by ID order by ID) as Rn, Security,sum(MValue) over(partition by ID) as MValue,sum(Bvalue) over(partition by ID) as BValue,ID
from  Yourtable
)
Where RN=1
```